Embedding a C library and its dependencies into a Flutter iOS app
I am trying to use a C library in my Flutter iOS app (https://github.com/quiet/quiet)
I have compiled the library and its dependencies into separate dylibs targeting the iOS platform but have no idea how to call the functions within my Flutter app.
I read the Flutter documentation on binding to native code (https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/c-interop#compiled-dynamic-library) but having minimal experience in iOS native development and CMake, I still have no idea how to do it.
Apreciate if someone could provide me with a Hello World example on what I need to do.

As the 3rd party library is open source, you will find it easier to follow the next paragraph: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/c-interop#open-source-third-party-library Note that CMake isn't relevant to iOS. Also note that most Flutter/Dart ffi questions are tagged dart-ffi and this is where you will find earlier questions.
